# Session timeout plugin

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, session

I am using organe hill's jquery session timeout plugin https://github.com/orangehill/bootstrap-session-timeout

But i am not able to properly align logout and stay connected buttons.Ui image is in link https://ibb.co/eHPMtF

This is code used in angular's controller for it.

```
$.sessionTimeout({
        logoutBtn:"",
        logoutUrl: '/aps/login',
        redirUrl:'/aps/login',
        warnAfter: 5000,
        redirAfter: 120000,
        ignoreUserActivity:true,
        countdownBar: true,

    });
```

can anyone help me aligning or removing logout button from it.

Comment: Looks like they aren't in the same "container" and they don't share the same class (not that they have to...). Please share some more code, so it's easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen of the plugin; it is based on twitter bootstrap as it loads a modal with the following footer

```
<div class="modal-footer"> \
    <button id="session-timeout-dialog-logout" type="button" class="btn btn-default">' + opt.logoutButton + '</button> \
    <button id="session-timeout-dialog-keepalive" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">' + opt.keepAliveButton + '</button> \
</div>
```

Can you please :

- tell which version of twitter bootstrap you use as a dependency ?
- do you have 3.3.2 as recommanded on bower.json ?

---edit after reply
I don't know if 3.3.2 as differences registered on modal to 3.3.7. Y
ou may try to downgrade your version of boostrap

> bower install boostrap#3.3.2 --save

--- end of edit

If yes; can you please :

- inspect your code with Google Developer
- see if there is any css overide on the footer OR on the button ?

Comment: Please if your comment leads later to an answer, edit it to present it. Thank you.

Comment: edit done. even if it does not leads to an answer @DIEGOCARRASCAL

Comment: @aorfevre I am using 3.3.7

Comment: I don't know if 3.3.2 as differences registered on modal to 3.3.7. You may try to downgrade your version of boostrap bower install boostrap#3.3.2 --save

Comment: this is another issue / request. Make a separate question & close that one